# Access to be provided to only one info path form and nothing else on the site

Tags: sharepoint-2013

how to provide restricted read access to a `sharepoint` site to an external user who does not belong to the organization.

Access to be provided to only one infopath form but the site should not be visible

Comment: You should move this question to http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/  . You will get more response there .

Answer (score 0):

Are you asking about granting access to an individual list item or multiple items in a list? I would add a column with a checkbox labeled something along the lines of "external access" and have a separate list that does a lookup on all items with that value, then you can grant your external consultants (or whomever) access to just the "lookup list."